# Get date/time for specific region?

Tags: c#, datetime, region

How do I get `DateTime.Now` for specific region?

I'm trying to get the current date in a foreign country, I'm looking for an easy way to achieve this.

Note: I don't mind getting the value from an online server, I just don't want to spend too much dev-time for it.

Comment: Console application, it doesn't really matter does it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know the timezone you want, you can use the [`TimeZoneInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.aspx) class. First [get the `TimeZoneInfo` object for your desired timezone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.findsystemtimezonebyid.aspx), then convert current time to that timezone:

```
var timezone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central America Standard Time");
var dateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.Now, timezone);
```